# 2 Map Tasks are started even though the input is less than the block size, What Determines the number of Map tasks?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am running a single machine Hadoop setup on an EC2 micro instance.
I wrote a simple wordcount program and without specifying explicitly the number of Map or Reduce tasks that should be run, the input file is <1MB.
The number of Map Tasks started in this case is 2, Why so?

If I use conf.setNumMapTasks(1) then only 1 Map is started.

**How does M/R decide that 2 Map tasks are needed even though the input file is <1MB?**

Comment: What's the block size of the file? `hadoop fs -stat "%o" /path/to/file`

Comment: @ChrisWhite `root@domU-12-31-39-06-C0-DF:~/hadoop-1.1.2/bin# ./hadoop fs -stat "%o" /root/input/pg4300.txt

67108864`

Answer (score 0):

The default number of map tasks per job is 2. That is the default value for "mapred.map.tasks" property is 2.

Verify the documentation here:
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred-default.html

Comment: I think that is the default number of Maximum Map Slots that can be allocated per node.  it is not the number of maps that a job will be using!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the Default number of map tasks per job is 2. There are two terms in Hadoop block size and inputsplit. The number of maps are generally decided by inputsplits of the Mapper Task.